# Update not working C# ADO.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I've been at this for hours and cannot find the issue here. I have 3 pages, 2 of which have updates and are working fine, but this one not which I'm hoping someone might be able to find where the issue lies..

Everything 'appears' to work, I see the 'sucessfully updated' message but it just does not update the data.

Here are the relevant snippets of code:

ASCX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="TestDataList" runat="server" onItemCommand="Item_Command">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class='<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "list-wrap" : "list-wrap alternate" %>'>
                <a href="#" class="edit-list icon-pencil icon-large"></a>
                <div class="update">
                    <span class="dl-content">
                        <h2><asp:Label ID="TestNameDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="name" Text='<%# Eval("TestName") %>'/></h2>
                    </span>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteTestCase" CssClass="delete-list icon-trash icon-large" runat="server" CommandName="deleteTestCase" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TestCaseID")%>'/>

                    <%--edit form--%>
                    <span class="dl-update">    
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUpdateTestName" runat="server" CssClass='textEntry' Text='<%#Eval("TestName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="EditTestNameButton" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="SelectTestName" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TestCaseID")%>' ValidationGroup='<%# "UpdateTestCaseName" + Eval("TestCaseID") %>' />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UpdateTestNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtUpdateTestName" CssClass="formValidation" ErrorMessage="What good is a test case with no name?" ValidationGroup='<%# "UpdateTestCaseName" + Eval("TestCaseID") %>'/>
                    </span>
                </div>
</ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Item_Command(Object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "SelectTestName")
        {
            string setTestNameSQL = "UPDATE TestCases SET TestName = @TestName WHERE TestCaseID = " + e.CommandArgument;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            SqlCommand cmdUpdateTestName = new SqlCommand(setTestNameSQL, conn);

            TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TxtUpdateTestName");

            SqlParameter u1 = new SqlParameter("TestName", tb.Text);
            SqlParameter u2 = new SqlParameter("TestCaseID", e.CommandArgument);

            cmdUpdateTestName.Parameters.Add(u1);
            cmdUpdateTestName.Parameters.Add(u2);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdUpdateTestName.ExecuteNonQuery();
                PopulateTestList();
                lblUserFeedbackMessage.Text = "Sucessfully updated!";
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Update Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Buddy !!! Don't worry . You just missed the @ symbol in sqlparameter object name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
string setTestNameSQL = "UPDATE TestCases SET TestName = @TestName WHERE TestCaseID = @TestCaseID";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
SqlCommand cmdUpdateTestName = new SqlCommand(setTestNameSQL, conn);

TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TxtUpdateTestName");

SqlParameter u1 = new SqlParameter("@TestName", tb.Text);
SqlParameter u2 = new SqlParameter("@TestCaseID", e.CommandArgument);

cmdUpdateTestName.Parameters.Add(u1);
cmdUpdateTestName.Parameters.Add(u2);
```

Otherwise you don't provide the values for the parameters, because the `@` is missing and your command is vulnerable for an [sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Ah thank you. I've accepted your answer as it was nicely detailed. I think I missed the @ at the start and then slowly made it worse while trying to 'fix' it :P

Comment: Actually, it's still not saving - my code now matches what you've suggested but its not updating the name of the test case..??

Comment: @Goose Has your database actually a row that matches your `TestCaseId`? Please check if `e.CommandArgument` is a String. If not add a `.ToString()`

Comment: Hi, Yes there is a table row which has the id of 10 which is also saved as a string for e.CommandArgument when I check through the debugger. Very strange..

Comment: it seems as though the textbox value is always the original value even after I input new characters so its saving its original value each time or something like that as far as I can see. I just can't see why.

Comment: @Goose Do you check in your `Page_Load` method the binding of data with `Page.IsPostBack == false`? If not, every time you click save the original data will be saved right before the `Item_Command` method will be called.

Comment: that was it! I had it outside of a the if(!Page.IsPostBack) check. Thanks very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the **@(Symbol)** in sqlparamete object Name ,For your Query parameter object name is @TestName .But you have   used SqlParameter Name is @TestName  .Missed the **@** symbol

Try below line for instead of that line of your code

```
       SqlParameter u1 = new SqlParameter("**@TestName**", tb.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using SqlParameters which is a good thing as it avoids the *Sql Injection* but then why are you passing the `e.CommandArgument` directly to update query. so change it to

```
string setTestNameSQL = "UPDATE TestCases SET TestName = @TestName WHERE TestCaseID = @TestCaseID";
```

and add parameter like this(don't forgot to add `@` before the parameter name)

```
SqlParameter u1 = new SqlParameter("@TestName", tb.Text);
SqlParameter u2 = new SqlParameter("@TestCaseID", e.CommandArgument)
```